# How to write an efficient wrapper in Ruby for an external application?

Tags: ruby, external, wrapper

I have this external application written in C that is invoked on the command line like this:

```
 app [options] <metadata file> < <input file> > <output file>
```

The metadata is basically a text string and the input and output data is basically tabular text.

I want to run this application in a tight loop from Ruby. How can I do this most efficiently? I want to keep the input and output data in memory, and I want to avoid writing the metadata to disk every time I loop to avoid disk IO overhead - and this seems to be conflicting with a popen/popen3 solution.

Comment: We need to see examples of what you've tried, and why they failed. As is, this seems like a very simple problem based on what you've described, and `popen`/`popen3` would work fine.

Comment: I can make it work with popen/popen3 (http://pastie.org/5512735) but my concern is that its slow.

Comment: How big is the meta data file? KB? MB? GB? Have you timed the load/read to see if its even worth worrying about?

Comment: The meta data is a few bytes, but there are hundreds of millions of iterations. Of cause I can write the metadata before hand, but I would like this method to be like String.scan which takes the pattern as argument for every invokation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the C code, then it'd be easy to rewire it to take its inputs from STDIN and pass it a JSON string to let it gather the needed metadata and input. The output could remain whatever format it is now, or could be JSON if you want.

If you don't have access to the code you're going to have to work within the constraints of that app, which means reading from disk. You could try to fool the app with pipes or Unix sockets for the input and output files, but I suspect it's probably still going to hit the disk somewhere along the way as a temporary buffer or cache.

I think your best bet is to ask on superuser.com how to fool the app into reading its input and meta data from a non-disk file.

---

Another thought is, if you had the code to the C app, you could read/write to a memcached store from Ruby and the C code, which would give you very fast I/O.

Comment: Thanks, I think that Perl extensions has a (database) adaptor function that can be used to eliminate disk access. I wonder if Ruby has something similar.

Comment: SQLite can use an in memory database, and that's easy to use from any DB driver or ORM, but that won't replace a file if the called app expects one.

Comment: I have access to the C code (http://biopieces.googlecode.com/files/scan_for_matches.tar.gz), but that code is "frustrating" to look at :o/.